# jquery validation on duplicated fields wont highlight on clones

Tags: jquery, validation, duplicates, clone, highlight

I'm cloning some select boxes on my form using

```
var o = settings;
var obj = $(this);
var objMatrix = $("div#dup_idiom").clone(true);
var placeHolder = obj.find(o.placeHolder);
var processClone = jQuery.format(objMatrix.html());
placeHolder.append($(processClone(i++)).addClass('closeable'));
```

Dispatched by

```
obj.find(o.addRow).on('click', function(e) { ... });
```

Cloning works fine. This is a function that is called on document.ready so on page load I have at least one default cloned group already on the page.

The jquery validation works fine for the first dupe, including the custom hightlight function I'm using:

```
$(".selector").validate({
    highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
       if($(element).hasClass('langDep')) {
            $('#idiomArea').addClass(errorClass);
        } else {
            $(element).closest('.clearfix').addClass(errorClass);
        }
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) {
        $(element).closest('.clearfix').removeClass(errorClass);
   }
});
```

When I duplicate the group, the validation will put the message on the dup if incorrect, but it won't leave it highlighted, what's wrong with my hightlight function?

As far as I can see on debug, it applies the hightlight, but for some reason, it calls the unhighlight just after highlight on clones and I don't understand why.
Thanks.

Comment: can we see your markup? You should try logging the elements to see which elements are getting passed into each function.

Comment: Added jsfiddle to original post, hope someone can point me to the right direction :)

Comment: It doesn't seem like the validation is working at all here...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized what's wrong.

I was using this custom validation to validate two select boxes, only if the first one was selected:

```
$.validator.addMethod("langDeep", function(value, element) {    
    if(!$(element).parent().prev().children("select").val()) return true;
    return value;
}, "Please select both the item and its amount.");
```

The issue was that I was trying to highlight an area, instead of individual elements for this part of the form. It was working for the first dupe and not for all the other dupes.
Turns out that the validation would return true if at least one of the group is correct, that's why it worked for the first one and never for the dupes, the first one was always correct!
The trick was to set the custom validation to operate as a group validation instead. Like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod("langDeep", function(value, element) {
    var v = true;
    $('.dup_idiom_area').find('select.langDeep').each(function(){
         if(!$(this).val() && $(this).parent().prev().children("select").val()) {
            v = false;
         }
    });
    return v;
 }, "Please select both the item and its amount.");
```

Now, hightlight work for the whole form as expected.
That was so dumb. I feel terrible. Sorry if I have made someone else's brain bleed unicorn tears with this.